# Jms Java: Deploy with version in weblogic throw javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException

Tags: java, deployment, jms, weblogic, spring-jms

I have a Jms `war` deployed in weblogic server. If I update this war with a new version, until the first version going to retreat I have 2 `war` that are using the same broker `tcp://0.0.0.0:61616`.

It throw

> javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: org.apache.activemq:type=Broker,brokerName=localhost

What I have to do for evict this address conflict?

I have to do it without remove old war and after install the new. Because the Jms must be always activate.

Answer (score 0):

What you are suggesting is that you open more than one Listening Sockets on the same IP:PORT, which is not feasible.

I would suggest splitting up your application into two parts :

- the activemq server part, that will always be up and running as long as the WebLogic sever is up and running and
- the application logic part, which will connect to the activemq server like any other client and handle the messages